# layout_weight in android is not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android, 
Im trying to set an

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

on editView .

first of all, its quite odd, because I cant see it on the properties window.

and when I set it on the code, it does not do anything

this is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".StatusActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

why does the layout_weight doesnt show in the properites window ?
and how come does it doesnt do anything when I place it on the code?

Comment: `layout_weight` is for `LinearLayout`s, `RelativeLayout`s will ignore it.

Comment: so the wrapping Layout should be Linear?

Comment: I don't know what design you are trying to achieve so I can't really comment :) But yes, in order for your `layout_weight` to be respected, the containing layout must be a `LinearLayout`

Comment: @thormayer it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @thormayer are you trying to set the width of EditText to be equal to screen width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layout_weight` is for views in [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will only use **layout-weight** for Linear layout.

And other thing is you put an **weightsum** is equal to some value to Linear layout and distribute equally weight to the views by using **layout-weight**.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning weight to layout is only eligible for `Linear Layout`. Rest of the layouts will ignore this.